# nodejs, how to using module.exports to set multiple parameters in express router

Tags: node.js, express

for example:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var routesTemp=require('./routes/temp');
var routesTempExport=require('./routes/temp_export');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'mustache'); 
app.engine('mustache', require('hogan-middleware').__express); 

app.use('/',routesTemp);
app.use('/',routesTempExport);
module.exports = app;
```

/routes/temp.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/temp',function(req, res, next){
   //how to set a object,function...etc in there to module.exports
   res.end();
});
   // or there to set
module.exports = router;
```

/routes/temp_export.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var getParameters = require('./temp');    

router.get('/temp_export',function(req, res, next){
    //and how to use getParameters to get multiple;
    res.end()
});


module.exports = router;
```

I tried to change the module.exports format 
for example:

```
module.exports = {router:router,obj1:obj1};
module.exports = [router,obj1];
module.exports = router,obj1;
```

But did not succeed, and will lead to `router` can not be identified

Comment: I don't really get what you would like to do exactly. Why not put all the routes (i.e. the code you included in temp_export.js and in temps.js) in a single router file? From my interpretation, what you want is first apply the temp.js function to do stuff then use its result in temp.exports.js but it's not really clear...

Comment: Everything seems to be correct . try to give app.use('/temp,routesTemp); and app.use('/',routesTempExport); You are exporting two router one in temp.js and another in temp_export.js and you are using app.use('/') for both so I think some ambiguity is occuring may that is the problem. Try to use different names for exporting and add some parameter to differentiate both.

Comment: I think so, so this is a bad practice ..? But is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set this in your module:

```
// in myModule.js
module.exports = {router:router,obj1:obj1};
```

Then, you can access both variables upon import by:

```
const myModule = require('myModule.js');
console.log(myModule.router);
console.log(myModule.obj1);
```

You do have to make absolutely sure that the two exported properties are already set when you export.  If they get set sometime in the future via some async operation, then you have no idea if they will be set properly when you want to use them.

---

In looking at the comments in your code some more, it appears that you're trying to use a value computed in a route in `temp.js`, in a separate route in `temp_export.js`.  You basically can't do that directly because routes come from all sorts of users so you can't store state from one route in any sort of global on your server and expect some other route to access that state (well, you could, but it wouldn't work properly most of the time).

Instead, what you would typically do is store that state in some way that is clearly identified with a specific client.  Then, when that particular client makes the next request and that route gets the request, that route handler can check the client-specific store to see if there is some state there.  Note that creating this state in the first place violates some principles of the REST design so your first design idea should be how to avoid doing this at all.  It would be better to put the state into the webpage returned from the first route and then when it makes the next web request, it can include that state in a query parameter.

The usual places you can store client-specific state are:

1. By putting it into the returned web page (so the client can pick up that state to send it with the next request - often as a query parameter or in a form post).
2. By putting the state into a cookie.  The cookie values will then be available to the server upon the next request.
3. By storing it in a server-side session that is uniquely tied to that browser/user.  The server-side session state for a particular user is also available to the server upon the next request.

Remember that the more stateless your server is the better (in general).  So, if there is temporary state relevant to a particular user, you'd like that to be stored in the browser and presented back to the server with the next request, rather than having the server try to keep track of it in between requests.

Comment: @AlbertChen - Added info on using data from one route in another route.

Comment: thank.I would also like to know,if I set the`module.exports =
 {router:router,obj1:obj1};`, for example, when the browser load http://localhost:3000/temp_export, express can not be identified `router`. How to I do?

Comment: @AlbertChen - `module.exports` is generally not for use inside the browser unless you're using some framework that you load modules through.   `module.exports` is node.js convention.  And, `express` is only for use on node.js, not in the browser.

Comment: Sorry I may not have made it clear. I mean when I set `module.exports = router;` in /routes/temp.js, when I `get` (localhost:3000/temp_export), it can succeed in finding `router.get('/temp_export',function(req, res, next){
    res.end()
});`, but `module.exports = {router:router,obj1:obj1};`...etc. this setting will cause `router` can not recognize `/temp_export`.

Comment: @AlbertChen - Well, you did `app.use('/',routesTempExport);`  That means that routesTempExport need to be your route handler function.  If you export `{router:router,obj1:obj1};`, then you need to do `app.use('/', routesTempExport.router);`.